# it's possible export a db from mongo to csv with commands in the mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, csv, export-to-csv

The problem is to export a CSV without using command lines for the system (mongodump, mongoexport). Is there any such command inside the mongo shell to do it? Thanks for your answers.